# Quickblox key exchange

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm learning how to implement a chat using quickblox with [this tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Overview). I like to know how to implement the key exchange protocol over that code. Could you help me with some idea to start that implementation?

Comment: What is 'key exchange protocol'? Can you add more info with links to your question

Comment: Any news here for us?